# Navbar below header responsive issue

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to get my blog up, but I'm stuck with this issue. I'm trying to get a header at the top with a starry design, then a small navbar just below it, but whenever I resize the page, the header image goes up on the page, and the navbar below gets disconnected from it. How do I attach the navbar to the header so when it's resized, they're connected and don't seperate? Here's my code

```css
body {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
   font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-image: url("./img/header-img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.item-right {
}
```

```html
<html>
    <title>Political Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/blog/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/blog/style.css">
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="header">
    
    </div>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="./latest">Latest</a>
      <a href="./all">All</a>
      <a href="./about">About</a>
    </div>
    </body>
<hr>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you call bootstrap and don't use it? That would be the quickest way.
Try putting anything in the header, it should change the behaviour since for some reason empty elements behave strangely.

Comment: You have set the height of the background image to 25%. 25% of what? With the code you provided the header is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ma5sn8c0/

```css
body {
   background-color: #D3D3D3;
   margin: 0 0 100px;
   font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/900x150/42f4aa/ffffff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size:cover; 
  background-position: center center;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.item-right {
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="./latest">Latest</a>
  <a href="./all">All</a>
  <a href="./about">About</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css property in header and use cover instead of 100% in css and position it.

```
background-size:cover; 
background-position:top center;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the working demo in code pen:](https://codepen.io/gudboisgn/pen/XaMqqQ)

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/1200/100/sports");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` 
to make responsive page inside `<head>` tag

```css
body {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
   font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-image: url("./img/header-img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.item-right {
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Political Blog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/blog/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/blog/style.css">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="./latest">Latest</a>
  <a href="./all">All</a>
  <a href="./about">About</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```